# Iterating through a python list of dictionaries using a xcom return value

Tags: python, list, airflow

I have an airflow step that utilizes this PythonOperator:

```
my_step = PythonOperator(
    task_id='my_step',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=metadata_iter,
    op_kwargs={'metadata': "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_metadata', key='return_value') }}"},
    dag=dag,
    retries=3,
    retry_exponential_backoff=True,
    retry_delay=timedelta(seconds=5)
)
```

This passes the xcom return value of the function 'get_metadata' to 'metadata_iter', which is another function and takes the argument, metadata. The get_metadata return value is a list of dictionaries. For now, it is only passing one dictionary in the list:

```
[{'a': '1', 'b': ['2', '3']}]
```

metadata_iter looks like:

```
def metadata_iter(metadata: list, **context) -> None:
    print(metadata)
    for x in metadata:
        print(x)
```

My issue: I'm unable to iterate through metadata dictionary in metadata_iter. The print(metadata) returns what I'd expect:

```
[{'a': '1', 'b': ['2', '3']}]
```

But print(x) gives me:

```
[
```

I guess it is interpreting that xcom value as a string, and not a list? Is there something I need to do in the xcom call to preserve the list?

Comment: As you already pointed out Xcoms are values which stored in STRING column at airflow metastore dbs. Thus when you want to convert them into python objects that is something you need to handle by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1**

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to evaluate that string

```py
import ast

def metadata_iter(metadata: list, **context) -> None:
    metadata = ast.literal_eval(metadata)
    print(metadata)
    for x in metadata:
        print(x)
```

or

**Approach 2**: Store it as JSON string and use `json.loads`

Store it as JSON string with [`tojson`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#tojson) Jinja2 filter.

```py
my_step = PythonOperator(
    task_id='my_step',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=metadata_iter,
    op_kwargs={'metadata': "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_metadata', key='return_value') | tojson }}"},
    dag=dag,
    retries=3,
    retry_exponential_backoff=True,
    retry_delay=timedelta(seconds=5)
)
```

and then load it with `json.loads`:

```py
import json

def metadata_iter(metadata: list, **context) -> None:
    metadata = json.loads(metadata)
    print(metadata)
    for x in metadata:
        print(x)
```